# how to execute a link in php file

Tags: php, curl

I have post.php file in which I want to execute testing file without any output to current page.  I have done the following code but its not working. Please any idea how to execute a link in a file without disturbing the post.php file.

```
$link = curl_init();
curl_setopt($link , CURLOPT_URL, "https://mydomain.com/testing.php?id=".$id);
curl_setopt($link , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($link , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$output = curl_exec($link);
curl_close($link );
```

Comment: Define not working. What have you done to debug this?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  What doesn't work?  What do you see when you `echo $link`?  Do you get any errors?  How do you know "it's not working"?

Comment: This https://mydomain.com/testing.php?id=".$id is not working in this code. If I echo it, it show me this 'resource(2) of type (Unknown)'

Comment: `$link` is a curl resource, and won't give you anything useful by echoing.  What does `echo $output;` provide? What does `echo curl_error();` provide?

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  curl_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in <b>/www/mydomain.com/post.php</b> on line <b>197</b><br />

Comment: Try `echo curl_error($link);` (see the documentation of [curl_error](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: @Aeykash: Typo, I meant `echo $output;` :-P

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working/basic working structure (for http/https).

```
$url = 'https://mydomain.com/testing.php?id=' . $id;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050414 Firefox/1.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

**TIP:**

`$url` = URL for page you want to fetch.
`$result` = Content fetch through the `$url`

`$result` will be string so you can do whatever you want with it.